# preg_match always returns true/1

Tags: php, regex

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm new to regex. For some reason no matter what I set $id to it always returns true.

```
$id = "tt0944557";

if( preg_match( "/tt\\d{7}/", $id ) ) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

$id will always start with "tt" then 7 numbers

Comment: you can try `/(tt\d{7})/` First it matches 2 t's, then 7 of any number.

Comment: `tt0944557` is a valid input so why should it not return `true` ?

Comment: Try "/^tt[0-9]{7}$/"

Comment: You don't give test $ids, but obviously this doesn't match any $id and seems to work as expected: https://3v4l.org/LRjBp

Answer (score 1):

This should work correctly, works on rubular.com tested:

```
$id = "tt0944557";
```

Regex is as follows:
`/^` to start matching from beginning of your string

`tt` match the first two characters must be tt

`[0-9]` only match if next characters are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9

`{7}` must be exactly 7 of these previous characters, so 1111111, 2232321, but not 123 or 332. {0,7} would say it may be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6 or 7 long

`$/` stop matching here

```
if( preg_match( "/^tt[0-9]{7}$/", $id ) ) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to regex as well, and would love to know, what makes yours a better answer than mine? Or are they basically the same? Also, I can't get yours to work using [PHPTESTER](http://phptester.net/), I think you are missing the ending slash in the pattern. Also I want to say, I'm not knocking your answer, I would legitimately like to learn more about your answer vs mine :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton no where did I say it was better? I simply submitted my version of the answer, an alternative regex match. Using full representation instead \d, because where I work \d would allow any digit, where as [0-9] I can also do [0-3] only allowing 0, 1 2 and 3 as possible options See  http://rubular.com/r/Hnf2hRNZNp

Comment: Fair :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$id = "tt0944557";

if( preg_match( "/(tt\d{7})/", $id ) ) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

What we need to focus on is obviously the pattern, `(tt\d{7})`.

The parenthesis mean `group`, as this is one selection, the whole thing is one group. The next part is the `tt`, these are literals. It finds the literal string "tt" in the input. The next part is `\d{7}`. The `\d` means *any digit* and the `{7}` means *exactly #* in this case, 7. So therefore it makes up the string as `tt#######`.

I built this pattern by using [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I tried this on regex101 myself but when i put it into a live script it was always true.

Comment: Well it would always be true if there is a match in the ID that you supply